# Error 404 When calling Restful Wcf Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, rest

I did the search again and again but I don't really know what am I missing.  I have WCF method and after calling, the service return with error 404, resource can not be found.

The url like this: localhost:3522/AccountService.svc/accountbalance/1

I run it from Visual with IIS 8 Express.

The WCF method like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAccountService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "accountbalance/{accountId}")]
    decimal GetAccountBalance(string accountId);
}
```

And this is my web.config

```
<bindings>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ProfileServiceDefaultBehavior"
    name="MyWcfService.AccountService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RestFulBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding" name="AccountServiceEndpoint"
      bindingName="AccountServiceBinding" contract="MyWcfService.IAccountService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="mexHttpBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestFulBehavior">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ProfileServiceDefaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by 2 ways:

1. For `Transport` security mode, `SSL` must be enabled and the service must be call in SSL channed.
2. For `TransportCredentialOnly` security mode, the Restful service works fine with `http`.

@adkSerenity: thanks for the SSL suggestion, and tracing.

Best Regards,
Vu

Answer (score 2):

Based on a brief review, the service section of the config file seems to be missing the baseAddresses element.

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:3522/AccountService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

In addition, you may want to consider enabling WCF Tracing and Logging, so you can review the WCF service startup events for any errors.  The following link provides a good overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Final note: since your service binding has [security mode="Transport"], make sure your server side certificate is configured correctly to support ssl.

Regards,

Comment: I tried that too, but no luck. One more infor, when I call http://localhost:3522/AccountService.svc/accountbalance/1. I got the `Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found.Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. ` But when I call http://localhost:3522/AccountService/accountbalance/1, I got another 404 page, but screen of IIS 8