# Restful WCF HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found when hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, iis

I am creating a simple WCF service which returns something like

> {"LoginResult":"Hello from WCF  (A)"}

I access the service using the blow from browser

> http://localhost:50908/Service/Login/A

It works perfectly fine from IIS Express when run from visual studio locally. But when deployed to a remote IIS i get **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**.I could view my service default page if i access

> http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8091/MyApp/Service.svc

. Here is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8091/MyApp/Service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="service" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!--endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I know this could be tricky and trying to narrow down further on the root cause. Tried creating a tracelistener, but nothing special in there. Did servicemodelreg -i. Looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655519/error-404-when-calling-restful-wcf-service) but not sure how to debug and which logs to confirm or proceed. Finally, this is my service method definition

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Login/{userName}", Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string Login(string userName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the address element. Should be like

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IService1"  behaviorConfiguration="webhttpbehavior">
```